# how to get in url with value.html

Tags: php, html, forms, webforms

This form submits url like that

http://www.website.com/page/search.php?search=demo&submit=Search

```
 <form action="search.php?search=" method="GET" id="search-form">
      <input id="search-text" name="search" type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="type keyword"/>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" id="search-button">Search</button>
</form>
```

Where I want to post the form like that:

http://www.website.com/page/search/demo.html

How can I do this?
I know it is a small thing but help me..

Thanks

Comment: `action="search/demo.html" method="post"` this?

Comment: in a form with the get method the url will have a ? after the action value then the name of the input boxes will be attached to the url with an = after then the value that was inputted i.e www.google.com?search=howtomakeaform&otherInputbox=otherInputValue

Comment: rizer this not only 1 url i have many words

Comment: NOT method POST Rizier123, that won't go on the URL,that will go with the headers,method must be get

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear what your question is.

If you mean that you want to be able to process the input client-side, that is not possible unless you override the behavior with javascript. For example with jQuery

```
$( "search-form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    // Do stuff here with the form data
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you mean that you don't want .php to show up and want to hide the underlying server technology, then you can use something like [Apache's mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/). But you probably don't want that in this case because .html implies that it's a page you visit (GET, not POST) rather than a script you submit variables to.

Comment: simple dear if user submit the button and write anyword like apple so form is post like this http://www.website.com/page/search/apple.html

Comment: Why would you want to do that instead of just going 1 page

Comment: If you want to do that, then you definitely need to use javascript. GET variables are appended after ? in the url. So you'd want to do something like:

`$("search-form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    window.location = '/page/search/' + $('#search-text').value + '.html'
    event.preventDefault();
});`

Answer (score 0):

Save this code as form.html on your desktop then open it with your browser then add some values and click the button. Look at the url afterwards

```html
<form method="get" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="input1">
  <input type="text" name="input2">
  <input type="text" name="input3">
  <input type="text" name="input4">
  <button type="submit">Click me and look at the url</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your edited question, try this with the above steps( save on the desktop etc.etc)

```html
<form method="post" onsubmit="this.action=window.location.href.replace('.html',inputurl )">
  <input type="text" name="input1" onblur="inputurl='/'+this.value+'.html'">
  
  <button type="submit">Click me and look at the url</button>
 </form>
```